# Why is my DataFrame printing out horizontally?

Tags: python, dataframe

I am trying to print the dataFrame in the end and the columns are not vertical. The numbers are horizontal:

```
# Data Manipulation
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# DataViz
import seaborn as sns
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Modeling
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
#from sklearn.linear_model import LinearRegression
from sklearn.neighbors import KNeighborsRegressor



#In order to prevent data leakage (when components of the training dataset leak to the #response variable and influences the model fitting, creating a wrong sensation of good #fit), we're spliting the data now, before any other formatting.
df = pd.DataFrame({'x':[1,3,3,4,5,8,10,9],'y': [2,4,6,8,10,12,14,16]}) 



x = df[['x']].to_numpy()
y = df[['y']].to_numpy()


X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(x, y, test_size= 0.2, random_state=12)

#x.reshape(-1,1)
#y_test.reshape(-1,1)

print(f'XTrain yTrain shapes: {X_train.shape, y_train.shape}  \n XTest  yTest shapes: {X_test.shape, y_test.shape}')

# Instance and fit
knn_model = KNeighborsRegressor(n_neighbors=5).fit(X_train, y_train)

# Score
score_knn = knn_model.score(X_test, y_test)
score_knn


# Predictions--Use the test data to evlauate the model's performance
preds = knn_model.predict(X_test)
preds
# Performance
performance = pd.DataFrame({ 'True count lost': [y_test],
                            'Prediction': [preds],
                            'Error': [y_test - preds]})
# View
performance
```

I ran the code above and instead of seeing a chart with values vertically, I received horizontal values and strange numbers added in. Her is the output:

```
XTrain yTrain shapes: ((6, 1), (6, 1))  
 XTest  yTest shapes: ((2, 1), (2, 1))
```

True count           lost             Prediction  Error
0   [[10], [14]] [[9.2], [9.2]] [[0.8000000000000007], [4.800000000000001]]

But I should get this:

True Value        Prediction    Error

10                        9.2               0.8

14                         9.2               4.8

Comment: Both `y_test` and `preds` are arrays, so lose the square brackets around them here: `{ 'True Value': [y_test],'Prediction': [preds],'Error': [y_test - preds]}`

Comment: Thanks Pavel, but when I take off the square brackets for y_test and preds I get this error:    ValueError: If using all scalar values, you must pass an index

Comment: Is `preds` a scalar for some reason?

Comment: No, i think it is an array